# 2 Modal show ordering for loading purpose

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm writing a MVC project which using bootstrap. I create the button, and add event onclick function.
For the view, I have make 2 modal. The first modal id call "loadme" (just for loading message). The second modal is the result screen which contain table.

The loadme modal is simple as like

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loadMe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <div class="loader"></div>
                <div clas="loader-txt">
                    <p>Check out this slick bootstrap spinner modal. <br><br><small>We are addicted to Bootstrap... #love</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the main result modal as below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalwnd2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Car Model Browse 2</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body no-padding">
                <div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;" id="CarSelectedList">
                    @Html.Partial("~/views/Home/_SubDemoTable2.cshtml", ViewData["CarRecords"])
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

At the  tag, I have do as below

```
$('#cmdCustPopup3').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('#loadMe show');
    $("#loadMe").modal({
        backdrop: "static", //remove ability to close modal with click
        keyboard: false, //remove option to close with keyboard
        show: true //Display loader!
    });
    var url = '@Url.Action("getCarList", "Home")';
    $.post(url, { _partialViewName:'_SubDemoTable3'}, function (data) {
        $('#CarSelectedList').html(data);
        console.log('#loadMe need hide');
        $("#loadMe").modal('hide');
        console.log('#loadMe hide end, modalwnd2 show()');
        $('#modalwnd2').modal('show');
        },'html'
    )
});
```

You will see , even I have added "$("#loadMe").modal('hide');", but the loadme modal is still screen. Can you advise what's wrong for that ?

Thank you

Comment: please provide a live example of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you added ***bootstrap.js*** in page? If not, try to include it and try again